# SQL Data types for Time

Tags: sql

What is the data type for hours in sql(i.e. timesheet hours)?

Appreciate your help

Examples
For field containing a word (ie Flower)the data type is CHAR and in xs:string
For field containing a number (ie 124) the data type is INT and in xs:integer
For field containing hours (ie 7.25) the data type is TIME (I think) and in xs: ????

Comment: Your questions seems a bit on the broad side. What are your requirements regarding those hour-values?

Comment: If you're talking about something like "hours worked", then why not just use an integer or a decimal?  Seems like it would make calculations easier, such as when using a time delta, payroll, total hours worked, etc.

Answer (score 1):

**DATE**, **TIME**, and **TIMESTAMP** are composed of a number of integer fields, represents an absolute point in time, depending on sub-type.